# Console application on Cloud9 instantly returning to prompt

Tags: node.js, console-application, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to create a code-gen like Yeoman in [Cloud9](http://c9.io/) yet for some reason my console instantly returns back to the prompt.

Yeoman is awesome and has figured out how to get passed this problem yet everything I try instantly returns.

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
prompt.start();
prompt.get(['username', 'email'], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return onErr(err);
    }
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  Username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  Email: ' + result.email);
});
function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```

[image: scr]

Comment: Do you have some code to post to show what you've done?

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/yA2Fv

Comment: [Works for me](http://i.imgur.com/KK5j3Uz.png). What other code do you have in your `index.js`?

Comment: Are you doing it in c9?

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/9SzvI

Comment: I'm guessing here, but since @laggingreflex was able to make it work on Cloud9, can you try deleting your `node_modules` folder, and trying to do `npm install` again (you have saved your module dependencies in your package.json, right? if not, save them before deleting)

Comment: Weeeeeeeeeird, the new workspace worked. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason when I have it inside of a function it wont run but when its outside of a function it works